Using WZUNZIP.EXE Command Line PowerShell to Folder
I have zip file called LatestFiles_20241130031004.zip that I need to be unzipped to LatestFiles_20241130031004.The zip folder structure is something like
LatestFiles_20241130031004.zip
----Folder A
----Folder B
---------Folder 1
----------File 1
----------File 2

When I use the code:
& $WinZipexe\WZUNZIP.EXE -d  "E:\TEMP\folder\LatestFiles_20241130031004.zip" "E:\TEMP\folder\" 2> $null

The result is
LatestFiles_20241130031004
----Folder A
----Folder B
---------Folder 1
----------File 1
----------File 2
----Folder 1
----LatestFiles_20241130031004
--------Folder A
--------Folder B
-----------Folder 1
--------------File 1
--------------File 2
----File 1
----File 2

When what I'm aiming for is
LatestFiles_20241130031004
----Folder A
----Folder B
---------Folder 1
----------File 1
----------File 2

This is behaving if I do this directly from the command prompt rather than running through powershell.
Any ideas? Solution is probably so simple, but I've been working on this for awhile...need new eyes...

Wouldnt it be easier with Expand-Archive E:\TEMP\folder\LatestFiles_20241130031004.zip E:\TEMP\folder\ ?

As an aside: "E:\TEMP\folder\" is technically a malformed argument, because the \" sequence at the end is considered an escaped " by the target program rather than closing the string literal - both cmd.exe and Windows PowerShell pass this argument on verbatim, whereas PowerShell (Core) 7 now fortunately performs the required escaping behind the scenes ("E:\TEMP\folder\\")
